# If Integrated Information theory is correct, might ant colonies and beehives be conscious and self aware?

Tags: consciousness, mind

Julio Tononi proposes that consciousness arises when information is extensively processed and shared between components of a system (like the brain). Ants and bees (and some fungi) share chemical signals that maintain the hive. Could consciousness arise from the integration of all those chemical signals?

Comment: Much simpler systems are already "conscious" [according to IIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory#Criticism), such as logic gates connected in an expander graph, which is why in its present form it is a non-starter. But the general idea of a measurable characteristic that identifies material systems supporting what manifests as "conscious behavior" is promising.

Comment: Consciousness proper likely requires inference, whereas integrated information trivial may lack trained direction, such as the desire to make sense and prediction of input. Hives likely have this inference in some degree, so likely possess consciousness.